# Excel VBA Checkboxes English vs French

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, localization

I have an Excel file which needs to deal with checkboxes. The names of the checkboxes are defined automatically in French (due to my installation being french). For example "Case à cocher 100" instead of "Checkbox 100".

However, when our sibling company uses this Excel file, it crashes due to their installation being English.

Is there a way to make the following work for English and French?

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 488").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 383").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 467").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 461").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 460").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 459").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 458").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Case à cocher 8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

I can't seem to find a way to rename the checkbox's name.

Comment: This is a very common problem. Generally, you should not use any language specific code other than English to ensure that your code will run in other languages. I suspect that in your case it might be the à in your code. To avoid this, use a worksheet for naming those boxes. Use references to those cells that contain names. Depending on the language settings, you use another column.

Comment: This looks like a lot of repeated code. If you can, you should consider implementing a loop and doing the same thing to each of the checkboxes in your active sheet, using something similar to [what can be found here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-controls.html). This comes with the benefit that you don't even need to know the individual checkboxes' names. But I don't know if you need to address only specific ones... Even then, I'd consider defining a subroutine to handle this.

Comment: @ChristopherKyleHorton Yes I know for the loop. This is code that was built by an engineer who has no clue about loops. They realized it bugged so I'm in charge of fixing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check for the regional settings and then decide which one to use.

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim CBNAME As String

    Select Case Application.International(XlApplicationInternational.xlCountryCode)
        Case 1 '<~~ English
            CBNAME = "CheckBox"
        Case 33 '<~~ French
            CBNAME = "Case à cocher"
    End Select

    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(CBNAME & " 488").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
```

Comment: Works awesome!!